# Symbol for Set of Integer

Tags: symbols

I can use  `\mathbb{Z}` to represent an integer type
but what symbol I should denote a set of integer?

Comment: _A_ set or _the_ set of? Usually, in maths `\mathbb N`denotes the set of natural numbers.  You also can use `\mathbf N`, but then, you must use the same notation for all sets of numbers.

Comment: your question appears to be about notation rather than tex so may be off topic, but I'd normally denote the set of integers by \mathbb{Z} (with N being natural numbers rather than integers.

Comment: I believe the author is asking A set of integer instead of THE set of integers.

Answer (score 33):

You could use `\mathbb{Z}` to represent the Set of Integers!

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: You can use backticks `\`` to [mark your inline code](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/863) as I did in my edit.

Comment: Downvoters should leave a comment clarifying how the post could be improved.

Comment: Downvotes (at least in my case) are because the answerer didn't read the question. OP knows about `\mathbb{Z}` for _the_ set of (all) integers; he's asking for a notation that means _a_ set of integers. For example, the Python function `sum` maps a set of integers to their sum; it is a function of type $?\rightarrow\mathbb{Z}$ where $?$ represents the symbol OP is looking for. That said, this being a question about math notation, OP should have asked on MathOverflow. TeX StackExchange is for questions like "MathOverflow told me I want this symbol: ?. How do I typeset it in TeX?"

Answer (score 1):

Can use the following:

```
$\mathcal {P} (\mathbb{Z})$
```

Comment: It's useful here to mention that `\mathbb` is defined in the package `amfonts`.

Comment: package `amsfonts` and not `amfonts`