# Symbol for a set of integers in LaTeX

Tags: math-mode, symbols

According to [oeis.org](https://oeis.org/wiki/List_of_LaTeX_mathematical_symbols), I should be able to write the symbols for the integers like so: `\Z`. However, this doesn't work. Here is my LaTeX file:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathcal {P} (\mathbb{Z})$
\Z
\end{document}
```

I have also tried following [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/165032/symbol-for-set-of-integer) question. However, again, no luck. Here is my code:

```
\documentclass{article}\usepackage{amsmath}
\begin{document}
$\mathbb{Z}$
\end{document}
```

I suspect I need to import a package. However, I don't know which, and none of the sources I have mentioned seem to refer to a package I need to import. How should I proceed?

Comment: `\mathbb` is defined in the package `amsfonts`.  I have no idea where `\Z` et al. may be defined, and the linked page isn't helpful.

Comment: Some varieties of MathJax define `\Z` to yield `\mathbb{Z}`, but there is no such definition in standard LaTeX. You need to load `amssymb` (or just `amsfonts`).

Comment: Incidentally, you should *not* blindly trust the information stated on the oeis.org site. In fact, much of what's stated on that site is badly in error. For example, it says that in order to write `A`, `B`, and `E` in math mode, one can do so by writing `\Alpha`, `\Beta`, and `Epsilon`. And, to give just another example, there's a claim that `+` and `-` are unary operators. That's just wrong: by default, TeX treats them as binary operators. However, TeX has clever rules in place to adjust the spacing around the symbols if they're used as unary operators.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some general comments and observations:

- Assuming you use pdfLaTeX to compile your document, then unless you either load a font that natively provides "blackboard bold" (aka "double-struck") uppercase letters or load some other package which loads a suitable math font, you will need to load the `amsfonts` package in order to access the `\mathbb` macro.
- Loading the `amssymb` package "works" too, since `amssymb` loads `amsfonts` automatically.
- The pdfLaTeX kernel does not provide commands named `\N` and `\Z` by default. (Aside: I have no idea why the website you provide a link to claims that one can use `\N` directly in a LaTeX document.) However, as is shown below, it's rather straightforward to create macros named `\N` and `\Z` which, in turn, execute `\mathbb{N}` and `\mathbb{Z}`, respectively. (Or, if you prefer, load the `dsfont` package and define `\N`, say, via `\newcommand{\N}{\mathds{N}}`.)
- If you can use either LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX to compile your document, you may want to load the `unicode-math` package to get access to its `\symbb` macro. This lets you create double-struck characters not just for uppercase letters but for lowercase letters and numerals as well. An example: `$\symbb{ABCabc123}$`. A

The test program used to create the following screenshot employs pdfLaTeX and shows the symbols frequently used to denote the sets of integers ("**N**atürliche Zahlen" in German), whole numbers ("ganze **Z**ahlen"), rational numbers, real numbers, and complex numbers.

[image]

```
\documentclass[border=1pt]{standalone} 
\usepackage{amsfonts} % for "\mathbb" macro
\newcommand{\N}{\mathbb{N}}
\newcommand{\Z}{\mathbb{Z}}
\newcommand{\Q}{\mathbb{Q}}
\newcommand{\R}{\mathbb{R}}
\newcommand{\C}{\mathbb{C}}

\begin{document}
$\N \quad \Z \quad \Q \quad \R \quad \C$
\end{document}
```

Comment: In Addition to Mico's answer I would like to offer the command `\mathds` of https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/452113/128553 for comparison.

Comment: I usually suggest `\newcommand{\numberset}[1]{\mathbb{#1}` and then `\newcommand{\Z}{\numberset{Z}}`; this indirection makes it possible to change the font used for number sets in a single place.

Comment: The LaTeX part of this answer is excellent. The mathematical comments in the first paragraph seem erroneous and distracting: at least in my experience from academic maths and computer science, the OP’s terminology (“integers” including negative numbers, and “natural numbers” for positive-only) is completely standard; the alternative terminology this answer suggests is simply wrong. So that paragraph seems erroneous, or at best (if that alternative usage is standard in some other field) irrelevant.

Comment: @PeterLeFanuLumsdaine - Thanks. I've implemented your suggestion to drop the opening paragraph about math terminology.

Comment: It might also be worth mentioning `mathalpha`, which provides a comprehensive set of alphabets, font specimens, and scaling.

Comment: @Davislor - Thanks. I honestly think that the OP's main concern was, "why does neither `\mathbb{Z}` nor `\Z` work?" [Vincent's parallel answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/525542/5001) already mentions the `mathalfa` package and how it may be used to access various blackboard-bold fonts.

Comment: @mico Thanks for pointing that out. I upvoted his too.

Answer (score 5):

As said by others, `\mathbb` is defined in `amsfonts`. For example,

[image]

is obtained with the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath,amsfonts}
\begin{document}
\(\mathbb{Z}\)
\end{document}
```

However, I think it's worth here to mention the existence of the `mathalpha` package (see the documentation [here](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/mathalpha)) which allows to use many fonts with `\mathbb`. For example,

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[bb=ams]{mathalpha}
\begin{document}
\(\mathbb{Z}\)
\end{document}
```

gives the same output than on the image given earlier. But other fonts could be used, for example

[image]

is obtained by replacing `bb=ams` with `bb=boondox` in the preceding code, and

[image]

is obtained with `bb=pazo`.

Answer (score 4):

The other answers all say how to use legacy 8-bit fonts, which still work.  If you’re using modern fonts with LuaLaTeX or XeLaTeX, it’s enough to load `unicode-math`.  It also defines `\BbbZ` and lets you type in ℤ in your source.

You can also write `\newcommand\Z{\mathbb Z}` if you want that alias.

Comment: Hi, is it `\Bbb Z` (as MathJaX) or `\BbbZ` as have you written?

Comment: In `unicode-math`, `\BbbZ`, `\mathbb{Z}`, `\symbb{Z}`, `ℤ` and `^^^^2124` all work. `\mathbb{Z}` is what’s backward-compatible.

Comment: If you want `\Z` to work in LaTeX, you’ll have to define it yourself.

Comment: Thank you very much for complete explanation that I not know. My upvote there is :-)

Comment: +1. I thought that my expression -- "unless you load a font that natively provides blackboard-bold uppercase letters" -- was broad enough to comprise cases such as `unicode-math`, which loads a math font and contains instructions on what to with with `\mathbb`. However, I may have been too subtle...

Comment: @Mico Upvoted your edited answer!

Answer (score -4):

**tl;dr**

```
{\bf Z}
```

The traditional notation, and Don Knuth's preferred notation (mine too), for the classical sets of numbers; is to use a bold Roman letter, thus: **Z** (for Zahlen---German for ``numbers''), the set of integers, may be entered {\bf Z}

If you have a real need to use double-struck letters in imitation of writing on black-boards imitating (really!) bold-face type (e.g. **Z** has another well-known meaning in your work in a particular field), then see the above answers (but Mico's differentiation of the Naturals and Integers is perfectly backward).

P.s. I don't have an electronic reference of Don Knuth saying this handy, sadly, but one does exist I believe.

Comment: This is for plain TeX. The `\bf` command in LaTeX has been deprecated for 25+ years.

Comment: That may be, but \TeX\ deprecates lay-Teks.  It's not perfect, and LaTeX is useful, but not crap-throwing like booing \over and \bf.---By this I mean LaTeX deprecates itself more than TeX deprecates itself.  Hence LaTeX is more deprecated than TeX. Q.E.D?  The most deprecated system is probably M$ Wart or CrApple Pockes---though troff(1) is maybe a good contender.

Comment: I didn't want to say that LaTeX is better or worse than plain TeX. My comment was aimed to point out the difference: one can use `{\bf Z}` in plain TeX, but shouldn't in LaTeX. It's important because most people here use LaTeX and may be ill-driven by reading this post. Note that the question *specifically* mentions LaTeX.

Comment: One can, and, moreover _should_, use `{\bf Z}` in LaTeX, simply because it is what is done in plain TeX, and hence is the most portable.  The point of the XML-ish syntax of LaTeX is to help automatic transformation.  Using some silly alternative to {\bf Z} in no way aids programmatic transformation; and anything that it breaks is unportable crap that ought to be avoided; hence to avoid {\bf Z} is fundamentally at odds with what is probably the only good principle of LaTeX.

Comment: Sorry: one ***must not*** use `{\bf Z}` in LaTeX. Definitely. Portability between plain TeX and LaTeX has been out of concern for two decades.

Comment: According to whom?  Lamport?  One may; and I do.

Comment: OK, do as you wish, but then don't complain when you try this simple document: `\documentclass{memoir}\begin{document}${\bf Z}$\end{document}`

Comment: If you're going to parade an example of a class where that doesn't work---well that would be reasonable only if the question pertained specifically to that class.  The class used in the original question will probably never get rid of \bf --- let the quirks of the classes be.  Automatic transformation of text between classes is not so easy anyhow, so they don't really exemplify the virtues of LaTeX.

Comment: I'm really sorry that you insist in keeping your position. Really: syntax such as `{\bf Z}` has been deprecated for 25 years and *will not* be resurrected. It was a conscious decision by the LaTeX team and has proved good for several reasons. The question is about LaTeX and suggesting `{\bf Z}` is wrong.

Comment: You asked (rhetorically, I would assume), "According to whom? Lamport?". Leslie Lamport has *not* been a leader in the development of LaTeX for more than 25 years. For several years after the transition from LaTeX2.09 (the last version for which Lamport played an important role) to LaTeX2e was implemented in 1994, some backward compatibility with legacy LaTeX documents -- detectable by their use of `\documentstyle` instead of `\documentclass` -- was preserved in order to facilitate the adoption of the newer commands. In case you hadn't noticed, though: LaTeX has come a *long way* since 1994.

Comment: I feel you are more interested in the quirks of LaTeX over good typography and good mathematics.  If {\bf } is not preferred in LaTeX, then you might politely suggest the latest whiz-bang syntax for bold-face in your preferred macro language.  To suggest the whole answer is worthless compared to your own answers which obsess over peculiar constructs and notation is shamefully petty.